# С чего начать изучение архитектур процессоров?

Tags: c, архитектура, стек, embedded

Всем привет, занимаюсь кодингом на С. И для моей професии очень важную часть играет знание архитектур процессоров и вообще всего железа, которое взаимодействует с созданной мною программой. Посоветуйте с чего начать, желательно книги для чайников или типа того. Хочу полностью понимать как работает компьютер. Есть понимание как работает стек, указатели, выравнивание памяти и тому подобное, но хочу копнуть глубже и что бы это не было написано непонятными и сложными словами. Если у кого-то был похожие ситуации раньше, прошу поделится опытом как вы это изучали, спасибо)!

Comment: Вот http://easyelectronics.ru/files/Book/digital-design-and-computer-architecture-russian-translation.pdf отличная книга

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить в общих чертах (а начинать нужно с азов) то не плохо подойдёт книга Э. Танненбаума и Т. Остина "Архитектура компьютера". В неё доходчиво и понятно рассказывается и об общем устройстве процессора, и об периферийных устройствах. Книга так же рассматривает и более высшие уровни, например, то как работают ОС, как происходит выполнение программ и т.д.